# Using Handlebars object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I want to pass an entire object right into javascript, but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried the {{{data}}} approach and the {{data}} approach like recommended in another post.
I'm doing something like this in the handlebars file:

```
<script>
  var myData = {{data}}; // or even {{{data}}}
</script>
```

Both of these give me the exception: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier.
However if I do a

```
var myDataUrl = "{{data.url}}";
```

It works fine, but for the first case it prints out "[Object Object"]. Any thoughts on how I can make case 1 work?

Comment: Handlebars templates are *not* JavaScript. if you want to use them to *produce* JavaScript, you can, but you have to render them as plain text first, and then evaluate the results.

Comment: What's the best way to do that? A JSON.stringify({{{data}}}) seems to have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

To insert Javascript data directly into template, you need to make it into a legal javascript string and pass that string into the template.  It needs to be legal Javscript before it gets to the template.  Using something like `JSON.stringify()` is one such way to make legal Javascript, but it isn't the only way.

Here's a piece from a handlebars template of mine that inserts some javascript data structures into the HTML file:

```
<script>
// temperature data - array of arrays of the form [dateTime, atticTemp, outsideTemp]
var temperatureData = {{{temperatures}}};
// onOffData is an array of [dateTime, str] - where str is "on" or "off"
var onOffData = {{{onOffData}}};
</script>
```

And, the data passed to the template looks like this (the two method calls return JSON strings):

```
app.get('/chart', function(req, res) {
    var tempData = {
        temperatures: data.getTemperatureDataSmallJSON(),
        onOffData: data.getFanOnOffDataSmallJSON(),
        units: req.cookies.temperatureUnits
    };
    res.render('chart', tempData);
});
```

---

This results in a piece of an HTML file that looks like this:

```
<script>
// temperature data - array of arrays of the form [dateTime, atticTemp, outsideTemp]
var temperatureData = [[1412752013861,22.19,16.35],[1412753505591,22,16.15],[1412754286561,21.85,15.94]];
// onOffData is an array of [dateTime, str] - where str is "on" or "off"
var onOffData = [[1411786960889,"off"],[1411790853867,"off"]];
</script>
```

Note, I'm turning the data into JSON and passing that JSON string into the template.